# API call returning array of integers as a single value. How do I return it as separate integers?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, api

I am trying to find the average of the grades returned from an API:

```
"grades": [
    "78",
    "100",
    "92",
    "86",
    "89",
    "88",
    "91",
    "87"
    ],
```

However, it returns as a single value instead of an array and I am unable to find the correct average.

```
78100928689889187
```

To find the average I am using:

```
const average = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length;
<p>{average(student.grades)}</p
```

How do I call the grades as separate integers so I can find the correct average?

Full Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function StudentList() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const average = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length;

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        axios
          .get("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students")
          .then((response) => {
            setData(response.data);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            setError(err);
          })
          .finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
          });
    }, [])
    console.log(data.students);
    return (
      /* loop through the students and display the data */
      <div>
        {data.students?.map((student) => (
          <div key={student.id}>
            <img src={student.pic} alt={student.firstName} />
            <h1>
              {student.firstName} {student.lastName}
            </h1>
            <p>{student.email}</p>
            <p>{student.company}</p>
            <p>{student.skill}</p>
            <p>{average(student.grades)}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your average function should be like this :

```
  const average = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)) / array.length;
```

By default the numbers are taken as string and if you add a string with a string they concatenate. So we parse them to integer and we are good to go.

Happy Coding :)